# Check if all textarea of the same class have above 'x' number of chars

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check whether a group of textareas are have more than 'x' numbers of chars using the textareas class "inside"? **I need to check this inside a if.**

```
<textarea id="1" class="inside"></textarea>
<textarea id="2" class="inside"></textarea>
<textarea id="3" class="inside"></textarea>
<textarea id="4" class="inside"></textarea>
```

I mean each length > 'x' and not the sum of all of them

Comment: it's true that is very basic programming, but the question is clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible solution

```
var textAreaFound = $('textarea.inside').filter(function(){return $(this).val().length>=x}).length;
if(textAreaFound==EXPECTED)
    alert("all have at least X chars")
else
    alert("some textarea has less than X chars");
```

Comment: does this check for each one of them and gives true only if each one of them has > x?

Comment: this code check if there are EXPECTED textarea with class inside that has at least X chars as a value. if you don't know how many textarea will be in the group is not the best solution but you need to loop inside every textarea like the other answers ;)

Comment: sorry, i'm not understanding... If I have those four textareas as above, applying this single line would check if each one of them has more than x chars and retrieve true?

Comment: THAT'S IT! You're amazing! Ty so much! (I need to wait 4 minutes to select yours as the right answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
x = 10;

$( ".inside" ).each(function( index ) {
  if($( this ).val().length > x){
      //do something...
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
var min = 15;
var allHaveMin = true;
$('.inside').each(function(){
   if($(this).val().length < min){
     allHaveMin = false;
     return false;
   }
});

alert("All Have Min "+ min+ " : " + allHaveMin);
```

Demo `---->`  http://jsfiddle.net/zL2KP/1/